# Python date over start increase

Tags: python, regex, file, date, time

Problem about date from file, how can I increase date by one day with given start from file.

My file looks like:

```
13.12.2013.   

06:00 ZMBT televoting
06:05 Madhubala, igrana serija, 138. epizoda, r.
06:50 Tajne, igrana serija, 55. epizoda, r.
07:30 Naša kuhinja
08:25 TV izlog
08:45 Bratzillaz, crtani film, 7. i 8. epizoda
08:55 ZMBT televoting
09:00 Prva dama, igrana serija, 89. epizoda
10:00 Štrumfovi, crtani film, 20. epizoda
10:30 Pčelica Maja, crtani film, 5. epizoda
10:52 Monster high, crtani film, 404. i 405. epizoda 
10:55 Monsuno, crtani film, 20. epizoda
11:20 TV izlog 
11:40 Tokovi novca
11:45 Vijesti           
11:57 Biometeorološka prognoza
12:00 Madhubala, igrana serija, 138. epizoda, r.
12:50 Prva dama, igrana serija, 90. epizoda 
13:50 Tajne, igrana serija, 55. epizoda
14:40 TV izlog
15:15 ZMBT televoting 
15:20 Muzički program
15:45 ZMBT televoting 
15:50 Karadayi, igrana serija, 68. epizoda 
16:50 Po spisku, talk show
17:45 Krv nije voda, serijski program, 107. epizoda
18:39 International Health
18:49 Domaćica Ovako
19:00 Vijesti u 7, informativni program
19:28 Vremenska prognoza
19:29 Biometeorološka prognoza
19:31 Sport
19:38 Stanje na putevima 
19:45 Tokovi novca
19:55 ZMBT televoting
20:00 Kolo sreće
20:05 Madhubala, igrana serija, 139. epizoda
21:05 ZMBT 6, show uživo
23:55 Sport centar
00:00 Dolina vukova, igrana serija, 97. i 98. epizoda   
Reprizni program Hayat TV-a    
01:55 ZMBT televoting
02:00 Vijesti u 7, informativni program
02:30 ZMBT 6, show
04:45 Muzički program

14.12.2013. 

06:00 ZMBT televoting
06:05 Madhubala, igrana serija, 139. epizoda, r.
06:50 Takešijev dvorac, zabavno-sportski TV show
```

Problem is when date is in same day when midnight has pass, how can I make when 00:00 pass in day to get next date from file.
My example of code:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import sys
import re
import time 
import glob
import logging
from datetime import datetime
import datetime


def get_date_time():

    # Values for date 
    # Example         : '''YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-DD-MM, DD MM YYYY, MM DD YYYY'''
    # Example of time : '''(00:00:00, 00:00, 0:00 -- 24 Time) | (00:00, 0:00 -- AM, PM)'''
    ######################################################################################
    #Let's add some date/time examples

    ######################################################################################
    # TS -> 05h 
    # Calculating time 
    # Open File for checking
    input_file = open('date.txt','r')

    # Open Output file for writting
    output     = open('date_change.txt','w')

    for line in input_file:
        # Let's take date with regex on example --> 1/6/2014 (MM-DD-YYYY), Time --> 24h (0:00| 00:00)

        if re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}', line):

            line_date1  = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}',line)[0]

        else:

            if not re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}',line):
                line_date = ''
                print line_date
                # Start

        if re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}.*',line):
            line_start = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}',line)[0]
            var2 = line_start+' '+line_date1

            var = line_start

            if var > '00:00':

                var1 = var
                Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line_date1, "%d.%m.%Y")
                EndDate = Date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                print str(EndDate) + ' '+var1

            else:
                Date = datetime.datetime.strptime(line_date1, "%d.%m.%Y")

                print str(Date)+' '+var1

get_date_time()
```

If you could give me some help about this problem.

Output would be like this:

```
13.12.2013. 06:00 ZMBT televoting
13.12.2013. 06:05 Madhubala, igrana serija, 138. epizoda, r.
13.12.2013. 06:50 Tajne, igrana serija, 55. epizoda, r.
13.12.2013. 07:30 Naša kuhinja
13.12.2013. 08:25 TV izlog
13.12.2013. 20:05 Madhubala, igrana serija, 139. epizoda
13.12.2013. 21:05 ZMBT 6, show uživo
13.12.2013. 23:55 Sport centar

14.12.2013. 00:00 Dolina vukova, igrana serija, 97. i 98. epizoda      
14.12.2013. 01:55 ZMBT televoting
14.12.2013. 02:00 Vijesti u 7, informativni program
14.12.2013. 02:30 ZMBT 6, show
14.12.2013. 04:45 Muzički program
```

Here is my result, i mean code it works i just add some lines. Guys thx for help. here is my code if anybody need's help:

```
def get_date_time():

    # Values for date 
    # Example         : '''YYYY-MM-DD, YYYY-DD-MM, DD MM YYYY, MM DD YYYY'''
    # Example of time : '''(00:00:00, 00:00, 0:00 -- 24 Time) | (00:00, 0:00 -- AM, PM)'''
    ######################################################################################
    #Let's add some date/time examples

    ######################################################################################
    # TS -> 05h 
    # Calculating time 
    # Open File for checking
    input_file = open('date.txt','r')

    # Open Output file for writting
    output     = open('date_change.txt','w')
    date = ""
    var  = ""

    for line in input_file:
        # Let's take date with regex on example --> 1/6/2014 (MM-DD-YYYY), Time --> 24h (0:00| 00:00)
        if re.search(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}.',line):
            line_date = re.findall(r'\d{2}.\d{2}.\d{4}.',line)[0]
            date = line_date
            x    = date

            print date

        if re.search(r'\d{2}:\d{2}.*', line):
            line_start = re.findall(r'\d{2}:\d{2}', line)[0]
            line_title = re.findall(r'\s\w*',line)[0]
            global var_x
            var_x     = var + line_start
            var2 = line_title


            current_date = datetime.datetime.strptime(x, '%d.%m.%Y.')
            new_date     = current_date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)


            if var_x < '06:00':
                var1 = var_x

                print >> output, str(new_date)+' '+var1+' '+var2+'\n'
            else:
                print >> output, str(current_date)+' '+var_x+' '+var2+'\n'






get_date_time()
```

Comment: Please provide an example of the expected output.

Comment: My code thinking is, when start reach over 23:59h take next date and put it with all start's where day is passed 00:00h in next day.

Answer (score 0):

**New (this one captures the date and appropriately increments it)**

```
import re
import datetime

def get_date_time():
    input_file = open('date.txt','r')
    output = open('date_change.txt','w')
    date = ""
    currentDay = 1
    currentHour = 0
    dateobj = datetime.datetime.now()
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.isspace():
            if re.match(r"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\s*", line):
                dateset = line.split('.')
                d = dateset[0]
                currentDay = dateset[0]
                m = dateset[1]
                y = dateset[2]
                dateobj = datetime.datetime.strptime(d+"."+m+"."+y, "%d.%m.%Y")
                date = dateobj.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
            else:
                h = re.findall(r"(\d{2}):\d{2}", line)
                if h:
                    if h[0] < currentHour:
                        dateobj += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
                        date = dateobj.strftime("%d.%m.%Y")
                    currentHour = h[0]

                output.write(date + " " + line)
                print date + " " + line

    output.close()
    input_file.close()          

get_date_time()
```

**Old (didn't realize you were trying to artificially increment date)**

Unsure why you're complicating it with `datetime`? Perhaps you're trying to build something larger than what I see there.

However:

```
import re

def get_date_time():
    input_file = open('date.txt','r')
    output = open('date_change.txt','w')
    date = ""
    for line in input_file:
        if not line.isspace():
            if re.match(r"\d{2}\.\d{2}\.\d{4}\.\s*", line):
                date = line.rstrip()
            else:
                output.write(date + " " + line)

    output.close()
    input_file.close()          

get_date_time()
```

Comment: Hm problem is, if I can explain clearly. Start is show in day. When date is 13.12.2013. and show start's after midnight, like from example output, show must begin with new date in next day. If show begins in same day its a pretty stupid, because after 00:00 is new day. That's my problem about this example.

Comment: Ahh, I see - the offset is wrong, 13.12.2013. 04:45 is actually the 14th.

Comment: Thx for help, but I did my code. Ill show it now. Thx man for solutions.